# Need to add a parent node for existing XML Descendants

Tags: asp.net, xml

I have a XML like below. I want to surround any descendants nodes whose parent category id is same in a node called as  < categories >...< / categories >

In short the parent nodes which has parentcategoryid = 800096352 should be surrounded with  < categories >...< / categories >.

And also since parentcategoryid = 800096348 also should be surrounded with
< categories >...< / categories >

```
<category>
   <id>800096348</id>
   <name>Apples</name>
   <category>
     <id>800096352</id>
     <name>iMac 2</name>
     <parentcategoryid>800096348</parentcategoryid>
     <category>
        <id>800096376</id>
        <name>imac accessories</name>
        <parentcategoryid>800096352</parentcategoryid>
      </category>
      <category>
        <id>800096414</id>
        <name>test 1</name>
        <parentcategoryid>800096352</parentcategoryid>
   </category>
</category>
</category>
```

As per the above example the results should be as follows

```
<category>
   <id>800096348</id>
   <name>Apples</name>
   <categories>
       <category>
             <id>800096352</id>
             <name>iMac 2</name>
             <parentcategoryid>800096348</parentcategoryid>
             <categories>
                <category>
                  <id>800096376</id>
                  <name>imac accessories</name>
                  <parentcategoryid>800096352</parentcategoryid>
                </category>
                <category>
                   <id>800096414</id>
                   <name>test 1</name>
                   <parentcategoryid>800096352</parentcategoryid>
                </category>
             </categories>
        </category>
    </categories>
</category>
```

Comment: Check out this link. possible dup question.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203939/add-parent-to-xml-linq

Comment: Thanks Etch, BUT my issue here is that I want to go up until atleast 4 levels deep to check < parentcategoryid > value with < id > value of its parent and if its equal surround < categories > node. I am doing something like below, but also want to add extra < categories > node if parent-child relation exists.

DataRelation relation = new DataRelation("ParentChild", oDataSet.Tables[0].Columns["id"], oDataSet.Tables[0].Columns["ParentCategoryID"], true);
relation.Nested = true;
oDataSet.Relations.Add(relation);

Is there a way I can add a new parent node for all the relations? 

Thanks